# extern "C" extern variable in C++ program sought as a class variable.. how to declare it?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I have a code below. It is part of a dynamic shared library which is loaded by qemu program (a C program) using dlopen.

```
extern "C" {
extern uint64_t host_virt_offset;
}

int Driver::CallSetBareMetalMode( uint64_t * args_ptr)
{
    dbg_enter();
    
    (... some codes ..)

    baremetal_axpu_es   = (struct es_t      *)(args_ptr[0] + host_virt_offset);   // line a
    baremetal_axpu_regs = (struct reg_csr_t *)(args_ptr[1] + host_virt_offset);   // line b

    dbg_leave();
    return 0;
}
```

Because the variable host_virt_offset is defined in qemu (a C program), I thought it can be used inside this shared library with no problem. But when I run it, error occurs, and when I examined it using debugger, I found the code is looking for `Driver::host_virt_offset` instead of the global (and extern) variable `host_virt_offset`.  I know this through below near that line.

```
(gdb) print host_virt_offset
Missing ELF symbol "AXPU::host_virt_offset".
```

I tried using `::host_virt_offset` in lines a,b instead but it doesn't compile.  How should I declare and use the variable host_virt_offset?

ADD : (I couldn't connect to stackoverflow for a while)  I made a reproducible program. Here it works ok using method I used. So there is something else.  '

<< main.c >>

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t var_from_qemu = 0x12345678;

int main(void)
{
    void * dlh = dlopen("./libbar.so", RTLD_NOW);
    if (!dlh) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }
    void (*bar)(void) = dlsym(dlh,"bar");
    if (!bar) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

<<bar.cpp>> <-- shared library

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" {
extern uint64_t var_from_qemu;
}

class BC;

class BC {
public:
    void bar(void);
    BC();
    ~BC();
};

BC::BC()
{
}

BC::~BC()
{
}

void BC::bar(void)
{
    printf("class function : var_from_qemu = %lx\n", var_from_qemu);
}

extern "C" {
void bar(void)
{
printf("global function : var_from_qemu = %lx\n", var_from_qemu);
BC tmp;
tmp.bar();
}
}
```

<< result >>

```
$ g++ bar.cpp -Wall -fpic -shared -g -o libbar.so
$ gcc main.c -o main -g -ldl -rdynamic
$ main
global function : var_from_qemu = 12345678
class function : var_from_qemu = 12345678
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @Gerhardh it doesn't compile when I tried `::host_virt_offset`.

Comment: are you assigning something to host_virt_offset?

Comment: @GeekyJarvis, no I'll just read it inside the shared library. The qemu program will set the value.

Comment: Please post complete and unedited compiler error messages.

Comment: hey folks, I made a reproducible example but this time there's no problem. please consider what can be wrong in my original case.

Comment: The problem must have something to do with the difference between your reproducible example and the real code.  Please try to make your reproducible example progressively more like the real code until you get the same failure.  I suggest you start by looking closely at the definition of the `Driver` class -- there must be a reason why the compiler resolves `host_virt_offset` to `Driver::host_virt_offset` and that's the place where the reason should be.

Comment: Additional useful information you could provide: run `nm --dynamic --no-demangle your_real_plugin.so | grep host_virt_offset` and post the _complete and unedited_ output.

Comment: @zwol right, I'm trying to mimic the real case now. thanks.

Comment: I updated my example more like it (so that the C++ class member function accesses the extern variable), but here it just works fine.

Comment: Keep trying. The root cause of the problem is in code that you think isn't relevant. This is a common cognitive trap to fall into when debugging, so don't feel bad, but reexamine your assumptions.

Comment: I tried declaring the same named variable in class Driver, and copied the extern host_virt_offset there in a global function in the .so before main events. Now the host_virt_offset value is correct inside the class member function of course. and `print host_virt_offset` command doesn't complain in the debugger and shows the value(I think it's the class variable at that point). Now seg fault occurs while adding that offset and making it a pointer (at line a,b). Maybe I can do with this method to access the 'extern C extern variable'. Any comments welcome and appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The compiler and the debugger use different methods to find symbols, so your conclusion might be wrong.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond yes, correct. maybe I could see the address of the global and class variable to check (or use different variable names). I'm curious..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it.
I added the variable `host_virt_offset` in class `Driver` which is different from the variable `host_virt_offset` which is set by qemu.  And I copied the extern `host_virt_offset` to the class `Driver`'s variable `host_virt_offset` like below.

```
extern "C" int some_function_during_the_init(...)
{
... some codes ..
AXPU::Driver *axpu_driver = AXPU::Driver::getInstance();
axpu_driver->host_virt_offset = host_virt_offset;   // copy to the class variable
... some codes .. 
}
```

And the original code should be changed like below.

```
extern "C" {
extern uint64_t host_virt_offset;
}

int Driver::CallSetBareMetalMode( uint64_t * args_ptr)
{
    dbg_enter();
    
    (... some codes ..)

    baremetal_axpu_es   = (struct es_t      *)((args_ptr + host_virt_offset/8)[0] + host_virt_offset);     // line a
    baremetal_axpu_regs = (struct reg_csr_t *)((args_ptr + host_virt_offset/8)[1] + host_virt_offset);     // line b


    dbg_leave();
    return 0;
}
```

Now the host_virt_offset value is correct inside the class member function and `print host_virt_offset` in gdb command doesn't complain and shows the correct value(I think the gdb is showing the class variable at this code point).
This code is adding some offset to the qemu guest physical address to convert it to host virtual address (i.e., qemu program domain adderess). The args_ptr itself was guest physical adderss so I had to give the offset to the value too. (without it, seg-fault will arise as before.)

Answer (score 0):

The `extern "C"` makes no difference when declaring variables, it matters only for functions.
The reason is that functions in C++ can be overlapped but variables can't.

for example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
extern "C" {
    int n1 = 1;
    
}
int n2 =2;
int main()
{
    cout<<n1<<endl<<n2<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, `n1` and `n2` are accessed the same.

Comment: Right. I think I'll try your answer tommorow though I can at least access the variable now. Thanks.